# Default path to look for partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

In my `app/views/conversations/index.html.erb`, I am writing:

```
<%= render @conversations %>
```

hoping that it would find a partial named `_conversation.html.erb` inside the same directory, and use it to render each elements in `@conversations`. (The usual Rails way)

But I get a missing template error: `Missing partial mailboxer/conversations/_conversation`.

I am using a [Mailboxer](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer) gem, and there were no documentations for this. I know I could render a partial explicitly by `<%= render partial: 'conversation', locals: { conversations: @conversations } %>`.

Yet still, I would like to know why my app is looking for a partial for `@conversations` in `mailboxer/conversations/`, not `conversations/`, and if there is a way to change this behavior.

**More information**

```
<% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
  <%= div_for conversation %>
<% end %>
```

produces HTML:

```
<div class="mailboxer_conversation" id="mailboxer_conversation_16"> ... </div>
<div class="mailboxer_conversation" id="mailboxer_conversation_17"> ... </div>
....
```

Perhaps the `mailboxer_` in front of `conversation` has something to do with this situation also?

Comment: That's quite an odd bug. Looks like someone has reported the issue on github - I assume that's you (if not, I would subscribe to that thread).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because, in later versions of Mailboxer, models are namespaced under Mailboxer. (e.g. Mailboxer::Conversation, Mailboxer::Message.)

I [commented](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/issues/311#issuecomment-106969450) on the GitHub issue also.

Answer (score -1):

You could try providing the full path to the partial, e.g.

```
<%= render :partial => "yourfoldername/conversation", collection: @conversations %>
```

Comment: Mike asks for the reason, why his solution is not working as expected.